# How can I maximize the editor pane in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: editor, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, maximize-window

In Eclipse, I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or click the maximize icon in the editor pane to make the editor pane take up the entire Eclipse window, and then again to restore the pane back to its previous size exposing the other panes.

Is it possible to perform the equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA?

To clarify, I'm asking about hiding all other tool panes to show only the editor pane. I'm not asking how to go to *distraction-free mode*, because this is mode is completely "full screen", hiding all toolbars, window decorations, etc.

Comment: The same feature has Netbeans

Answer (score 326, accepted):

The closest thing would be to hide all tool windows by invoking the *Hide All Tool Windows* action. The shortcut for that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> (Default keymap).

This will hide all tool windows, effectively maximizing the editor window (though not full screen). The *IntelliJ* menu bar, toolbar, breadcrumb and tab bar will still be visible.

I'm using *IntelliJ 11.1.2* on *Kubuntu 12.04 LTS* with the *Default keymap*.

### 14.0.3 on MacOS X

It's <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> in IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3 on MacOS X.

**UPDATE on 2015-03-24:**
IntelliJ IDEA 14.1 now has support for *Distraction Free Mode*. You can invoke it by clicking View > Enter Distraction Free Mode. In this mode, IntelliJ hides everything but the menu. For more details, follow their video detailing the new feature: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVwE8MFgYig.

Comment: This is nice--though it would be nice if there were a maximize current view similar to Eclipse's.  This IntelliJ feature can only maximize the editor pane, where control-M on eclipse maximizes any pane--the project explorer, todo list (tasks), etc.

Comment: By the way, you can change size of any tool window by using a nifty shortcut. If a tool window is stacked on the rigth side (like Commander, Ant Build etc.), just use Ctrl + Shift + Left Arrow to increase size of the window in big chunks. Using Right Arrow while holding down Ctrl and Shift keys will decrease the tool window size. Similarly, you can use this shortcut with any tool window stacked at the bottom -- the only difference is you'll have to use the up/down arrow keys instead of the left/right ones. These shortcuts work for all tool window.

Comment: But I certainly agree that it would be very useful to have the capability to maximize any tool window and editor etc. with a simple shortcut.

Comment: @JeffAxelrod  There's a separate hotkey, ctrl + shift + "  (d-quote) to toggle-max a tool pane.  Yes, too bad it doesn't also work for the editing window...  You might be able to macro the two together, end up with one hotkey for the macro..?

Comment: @HawkeyeParker See the update to my answer. Distraction Free mode effectively gives you a shortcut to maximize a code editor window.

Comment: @ehsanullahjan Yes, thanks, I saw that. I actually prefer the "Hide all tool windows" mode; in particular, I want line numbers and tabs. My comment was really more about the lack of a universal hotkey for maximizing any pane in Idea. You can see [what I ended up doing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33457612/99717).

Comment: @ehsanullahjan I love you :) Its kinda obvious there should be some kind of this shortcut but I wouldn't know about it if I didn't came across this topic by accident :)

Comment: Lol, had to figure out by myself before finding this one. Recorded a macro of double-clicking on the window tab and then went to edit it to see what action was recorded.

Comment: Hide All Tool Windows is not even near the original feature of Netbeans, it does not hide any inactive source editor.

Comment: Distraction Free Mode is the closest one can get, but it still does not hide inactive editors.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to maximize a pane , select that pane (by clicking inside or on its title bar) and then use the shortcut **"<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Quotes</kbd>"**

Comment: great answer! For those who wants to maximise e.g. "Debug" pane, this is the shortcut you want!

Comment: How is this method inside Keymap tab called? I can find it by searching via Shortcut

Comment: @joaquin Maximize Tool Window

Comment: This only works for *tool* panes. It does *not* work to maximize the *editor pane* (which is the question).

Comment: What quotes exactly.  My keyboard layout appears to have trouble finding the right key.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The key which has Single/Double quotes (next to semi colon key)

Comment: @Ram Doesn't work on a Danish keyboard layout under Ubuntu.  But then I found out that Ctrl-Shift-[0-9] sets a bookmark that can be navigated to with Ctrl-[0-9].

Comment: Its close - but what If I want to fullscreen single editor tab on split editory layout? I wish to make fullscreen single "split screen" and revert as I have file that I am editing right now and 2 more split tabs as a code preview

Answer (score 28):

You can double click anywhere on the tab title bar of the editor pane.

Comment: I only discovered this today by accident, and it is _insanely_ useful!  (Note that you can also maximise tool windows — albeit only vertically — by double-clicking their title bars.)

Comment: Note that this only works on places where there is no label or tab or something.

Comment: but is there a way to attach the eclipse-like ctrl-m hotkey for it?

Comment: doesn't maximize single editor pane if you have two editor panes split window https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82829

Answer (score 8):

I use `Ctrl-Shift-F12`("Hide All Windows") toggle between maximum and normal modes of the editor.

Answer (score 8):

All answers work for only hiding other tools. If you have more than one editor **pane** and you want to maximize only one **editor pane** (hide all tolls and hide all other editor panes), it is not possible right now.

PyCharm version: 2018.2.7

Comment: That is what I am looking for... I have split view and I want temporally to zoom in one pane. This is similar to zoom feature of `terminator` cli tool.

Comment: thanks, seems here like 20 replies about minimizing tool window, but not maximizing a single one when you have two panes, as the question seems to be about, I wished I removed some votes I accidentally gave in the past, just to bookmark the reply https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82829

Comment: This is exactly what I was commenting about in the top answer. Netbeans had it also!

Answer (score 6):

Using IntelliJ 14.1.5

If you want to maximize the editor window AND full-screen the app, you can create a macro with the following two commands:

```
Toggle Full Screen Mode
Hide All Tool Windows
```

And then assign a hotkey to the macro. Here's how I did this:

- File > Settings > Keymap
- Use the search bar to search for the two commands above. Assign obscure hotkeys to those.
- Edit > Macros > Start macro recording
- Hit the two obscure hotkeys you just assigned: this should max the editor and full-screen the app
- Stop recording. Name the macro
- Open File > Settings > Keymap again.  Find the Macros section, find your macro, assign a nice hotkey to it.

Answer (score 5):

I just assigned `^M`(ctrl+M) to Main menu | Window | Active Tool Window | Hide All Tool Windows under preferences(by clicking `cmd,`). This worked for me exactly like eclipse. [image: Here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

something similar can be achieved by opening your tab in a new window.

The default hotkey for that is **shift+f4**.

the editor tab remains in the main app window as well, and the new window appears on top of the main app window.

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered, but since when I google "android studio maximize tab" this is the first answer I see, I'm going to add my two cents.

I hate the keyboard shortcuts since, at any given time, I have 1 hand on my keyboard and 1 hand on my mouse.  Having to let go of my mouse to hit a 3-key combination to maximize the current tab is not a shortcut.  What I was looking for was an Eclipse-style behavior: double-click the tab to maximize.  Here's how to do that:

In Android Studio, under Preferences, go to Keymap->Main Menu->Window->Active Tool Window.  Right-click the "Maximize tool window" mapping and select "Add mouse shortcut."

[image]

For "Click Count" pick "Double Click" and then double-click on the "Click Pad" mouse icon.

[image]

Click OK out of the menus and you should now be able to double-click on any tab and it will be maximized.  Double-clicking again will minimize it.

Coming from Eclipse to IntelliJ, this was one of the most frustrating aspects I've had to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

full screen plugin is availble for IntelliJ Idea...

https://github.com/jfim/ideafullscreen

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use the same shortcut like Eclipse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, to minimize/maximize the active editor window,
You can follow the below steps:

- Open (File > Settings...) or click ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> )
- Select `Keymap`
- Search for "Hide All Tool Windows"
- Change the default shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

[image]

Then you will be able to use the same shortcut as Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old question and the distraction free mode wasn't exactly what I wanted. This is because it does not hide other editor windows. With [2021.1 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2021.1+EAP+(211.5538.20+build)+Release+Notes) this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82829) has been resolved and maximising the editor hides all other editors but the active one.

Comment: There is an corresponding option at Settings->Advanced Settings->Editor Tabs.

Answer (score 0):

For people using IdeaVim trying to emulate the `<leader> z` behavior of tmux, you can use the following mapping:

```
map <leader>zz <Action>(MaximizeEditorInSplit)
```

Answer (score -1):

I searched for something like `ctrl+b z`in `tmux`. For me, the similar task solved by key combination `shift+f4`. It opens your tab in the separated window (which can be closed as usual, `alt+f4`). My PyCharm version:

```
PyCharm 2019.2 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-192.5728.105, built on July 23, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.10 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 725M
Cores: 8
Registry: 
Non-Bundled Plugins:
```