# Missing/hidden tools windows in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

All the tools windows have disappeared. I can still open them individually via the View->Tool Windows menu but how can I bring back the minimized area for them?

I only found posts about hiding them but not the reverse ([How to hide all toolbar/windows and buttons in Android Studio with a keyboard shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704839/how-to-hide-all-toolbar-windows-and-buttons-in-android-studio-with-a-keyboard-sh))

Who knows?

[image: no tool windows minimized]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In android studio toolbar window can be hide/unhide with **View->Tool Buttons**. You can check, it can be helpful for you

Comment: So simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**VIEW > APPEARANCE > TOOL WINDOWS BAR** (IF THIS IS UNCHECK CHECK IT)

Answer (score 2):

In android studio toolbar window can be hide/unhide:

- set checkbox **View -> Tool Window Bars**
- or double click on **Command** button on MacOs

Comment: Double click only won't work, but click once and then click twice and hold, when release the button the Tool Window Bar will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you enter `Presentation` or `Distraction` Mode.
So please exit them by the way:

> View/ Exit Presentation Mode

or

> View/ Exit Distraction Mode

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for suggesting but that is not it. Those will also make the top panel disappear (my image was cropped so you can't see it) but mine are still there. Just the right, left and bottom are missing